# wp rest api (v2) filter not working (404 error - rest_no_route)

Tags: plugins, api, rest-api

Filter for Wordpress rest api not working. I use simple permalink (another one-s not the variant) and my url looks like this: http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts this request works fine, but when i try to add filter http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts?filter[numberposts]=10 thats gives me error:

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"no route was found matching the url and request method","data":{"status":404}}
```

What is the reason of error? And how can i solve this?

I use nginx 1.10.2, Wordpress 4.7.5

Comment: You do realize that there‘s no filter param in the REST API? See https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38378

Comment: Okay, i got it. But how can i use "filters"? For example, how can i get more than 10 posts from this query? (by default it returns 10) http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/ Ty btw

Comment: Use the per_page parameter. Check out the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/

Comment: I did it, but i got error that i said above - "rest_no_route". And my URL: http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1

Comment: try with `example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts&per_page=1`

Comment: Yes! Thank you, mmm! And the last thing - how can i get specified fields? Here is my url: http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/1&fields?subject,author_name it returns me all fields. Also I tried this way: http://example.com/?rest_route=/wp/v2/posts/1/&fields?subject,author_name but same result

Comment: I'm prob wrong but, can't you just do example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20 ? Regarding limiting the returned fields, I believe I've seen a plugin for that, have a look at WordPress Plugin Repo.

Comment: I am using the same kind of URI as below ```
http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=10 ```